# Date logic in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The following formula works from most date combinations:

```
=IF(INT(B2)=INT(NOW()),"Today",IF(DAYS(NOW(),B2)>365,IF(DAYS(NOW(),B2)/365.25>1,YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(B2),0)&" years, ","")&IF(IF(MONTH(NOW())-MONTH(B2)<0,MONTH(NOW())-(MONTH(B2)-11),IF(DAYS(NOW(),B2)<28,0,MONTH(NOW())-MONTH(B2)))=0,"",IF(MONTH(NOW())-MONTH(B2)<0,MONTH(NOW())-(MONTH(B2)-11),IF(DAYS(NOW(),B2)<28,0,MONTH(NOW())-MONTH(B2)))&" months and ")&IF(DAY(NOW())-DAY(B2)<0,VLOOKUP(MONTH(B2),{1,31;2,28;3,31;4,30;5,31;6,30;7,31;8,31;9,30;10,31;11,30;12,31},2)-DAY(B2)+DAY(NOW()),DAY(NOW())-DAY(B2))&" days")
```

Except if B2 is *16/02/2015  15:19:00* and NOW() is *08/02/2016  14:54* where the result is *20 days* but should obviously be *11 months and 30 days*.
I'm struggling to find the hole in my logic.

Comment: What is this formula attempting to do?

Comment: It's a date comparison. If B2 was *15/07/2014* it would return *2 years, 6 months and 24 days*. If B2 was *07/05/2015* it would return *8 months and 1 days*. If B2 was *03/02/2016* it would return *5 days*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function appears to be using the Julian year length, rather than the more complicated Gregorian one. That's one reason why your function's robustness will be questionable.

Fortunately, Excel has a built-in function `DATEDIF` which you can use. But, for some reason, it's a hidden function! (I have absolutely no clue why).

If A1 and A2 contain the two dates, use

`=DATEDIF(A1,A2,"y") & " years, " & DATEDIF(A1,A2,"ym") & " months, " & DATEDIF(A1,A2,"md") & " days"`

A1 must be earlier than A2.

Comment: The last part seems to do some odd things for me e.g. if you try A1=31/1/15 and A2=1/3/16 do you get -1?

Comment: I saw other responses using DATEDIF but assumed it wasn't available in 2013 as it wasn't on the list of functions :s Thank you @Bathsheba

Comment: It is - but hidden for some reason. @TomSharpe: I'll check that corner case when I'm next in the office.

Comment: Thanks! To be honest it's difficult to know what the answer should be when the previous month (February) 'doesn't have enough days'.

Comment: Hm even more bizarre result with 30/11/14 and 1/1/16

Answer (score 1):

Since DATEDIF(date1,date2,"md") essentially generates random numbers when

```
DAY(dates2)<DAY(date1)
```

here's a possible formula solution (where my start and end dates are in A2 and B2):-

Years

```
=DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")
```

Months

```
=DATEDIF(A2,B2,"m")
```

Days

```
=IF(DAY(B2)>=DAY(A2),DAY(B2)-DAY(A2),DAY(B2)-DAY(A2)+DAY(EOMONTH(A2,0)))
```

Here are a few test cases:-

[image]

Comment: Indeed it does, Note I state "A1 must be earlier than A2" in my answer. Your approach looks promising. Plus one. (Btw, no hard feelings at all if you unaccept my answer and accept your own. It appears that your solution will be more useful to future users, which is what this site is all about).

Comment: Thank you for positive comment (I didn't make the original post but got drawn into it :-) )

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wanting to do the same, here's my working function:

```
=IF(DAYS(NOW(),B2)>0,CONCATENATE(IF(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"y")=0,"",DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"y")),IF(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"y")=0,"", " year"),IF(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"y")>1,"s",""),IF(AND(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"y")>0,DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"ym")>0),IF(IF(AND(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"md")>0,OR(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"y")>0,DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"ym")>0))," and ","")=""," and ",", "),""),IF(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"ym")=0,"",DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"ym")),IF(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"ym")=0,"", " month"),IF(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"ym")>1,"s",""),IF(AND(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"md")>0,OR(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"y")>0,DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"ym")>0))," and ",""),IF(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"md")=0,"",DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"md")),IF(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"md")=0,"", " day"),IF(DATEDIF(B2,NOW(),"md")>1,"s","")),"Less than a day")
```

which gives a result like "1 year, 5 months and 15 days".